# Which Job inserted this record / row into the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, reporting

I have dozens of different SQL Jobs calling different Sprocs, which insert rows into a common table.

Is there any way, given a row in the table, to retrieve the job which triggered the insert?

Input: Row ID, TableName, DBName

Output: Job ID which inserted Row

Answer (score 0):

Not generally, as far as I'm aware.  You could have the insert query include that data.  Or you could get it from a log, maybe based on the primary key or another unique key, if your inserts are unique.  You might be able to turn on some SQL server equivalent of the general log; but that's devastating to high volume performance and you'd still have to pull it from a log file.  I recommend you consider whether you can diagnose your components from their logs in addition to their effects in the database.